# CV Address with Photo alignment

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, resume, cv

I have a problem regarding to my resume alignment.
I want to show my address at top left of the CV and at top right show my photo. Here is a code snippet:

```
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % this page has no header  
\name{john smith\\[12pt]}
\vspace{0pt} 
        \address{{\bf Permanent Address} \\ lablab12, 12345\\
 somewhere, Europe\\ Tel:(+9) 1238421\\Email :abc@abc.co}     
\address{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CV}}
```

P.S: as a trick, to show the photo under my name I used `\address` command, but the photo again appears in this form:

[image]

As you can see photo appears on top of the address and not aligned to address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've shown there is no need for using the (archaic) [`res` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/res). However, if you insist, I'd suggest not using the title-related macros for setting that part of your document. Just set them as-is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{res}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % this page has no header  

\begin{center}
  \bfseries John Smith
\end{center}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  \bfseries Permanent Address \\
  lablab12, 12345 \\
  somewhere, Europe \\
  Tel:(+9) 1238421 \\
  Email :abc@abc.co
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image}%

\begin{resume}

Some content here.

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

The address is set inside a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular`, with the photo pushed to the right (using `\hfill`). [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `export` option makes options available to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` command. As such, the image is also `align`ed `v`ertically to the `t`op of the image via `valign=t`.